# Issue with ContextMenuResource

Tags: android

I can not get the `ContextMenuResource` to return the correct information that I am looking for.

At times it returns what I want, other times not so much so.

```
 public class montypython extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    private static final int SAVE_SOUND = 0;

    // Tag to easily locate errors in the log file.

    private static final String TAG = "Monty";

    // Declares the buttons.

    Button button0;
    Button button1;
    Button button2;
    Button button3;
    Button button4;
    Button button5;
    Button button6;
    Button button7;
    Button button8;
    Button button9;
    Button button10;
    Button button11;
    Button button12;
    Button button13;
    Button button14;
    Button button15;
    Button button16;
    Button button17;
    Button button18;
    Button button19;
    Button button20;
    Button button21;
    Button button22;
    Button button23;
    Button button24;
    Button button25;

    // Makes contextMenuResource available for use in other methods.

    public int contextMenuResource;

    // Makes MediaPlayer (mp) null and ready to go.

    MediaPlayer mp=null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

    // Set Views and Listeners and Tags for buttons.

    button0=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button0);
    button0.setOnClickListener(this);
    button0.setTag(R.raw.a);
    button1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button1.setOnClickListener(this);
    button1.setTag(R.raw.b);
    button2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
    button2.setOnClickListener(this);
    button2.setTag(R.raw.c);
    button3=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);
    button3.setOnClickListener(this);
    button3.setTag(R.raw.d);
    button4=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button4);
    button4.setOnClickListener(this);
    button4.setTag(R.raw.e);
    button5=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button5);
    button5.setOnClickListener(this);
    button5.setTag(R.raw.f);
    button6=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button6);
    button6.setOnClickListener(this);
    button6.setTag(R.raw.g);
    button7=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button7);
    button7.setOnClickListener(this);
    button7.setTag(R.raw.h);
    button8=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button8);
    button8.setOnClickListener(this);
    button8.setTag(R.raw.i);
    button9=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button9);
    button9.setOnClickListener(this);
    button9.setTag(R.raw.j);
    button10=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button10);
    button10.setOnClickListener(this);
    button10.setTag(R.raw.k);
    button11=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button11);
    button11.setOnClickListener(this);
    button11.setTag(R.raw.l);
    button12=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button12);
    button12.setOnClickListener(this);
    button12.setTag(R.raw.m);
    button13=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button13);
    button13.setOnClickListener(this);
    button13.setTag(R.raw.n);
    button14=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button14);
    button14.setOnClickListener(this);
    button14.setTag(R.raw.o);
    button15=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button15);
    button15.setOnClickListener(this);
    button15.setTag(R.raw.p);
    button16=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button16);
    button16.setOnClickListener(this);
    button16.setTag(R.raw.q);
    button17=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button17);
    button17.setOnClickListener(this);
    button17.setTag(R.raw.r);
    button18=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button18);
    button18.setOnClickListener(this);
    button18.setTag(R.raw.s);
    button19=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button19);
    button19.setOnClickListener(this);
    button19.setTag(R.raw.t);
    button20=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button20);
    button20.setOnClickListener(this);
    button20.setTag(R.raw.u);
    button21=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button21);
    button21.setOnClickListener(this);
    button21.setTag(R.raw.v);
    button22=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button22);
    button22.setOnClickListener(this);
    button22.setTag(R.raw.w);
    button23=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button23);
    button23.setOnClickListener(this);
    button23.setTag(R.raw.x);
    button24=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button24);
    button24.setOnClickListener(this);
    button24.setTag(R.raw.y);
    button25=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button25);
    button25.setOnClickListener(this);
    button25.setTag(R.raw.z);

    // Registering ContextMenu's for long clicks.

    registerForContextMenu(button0);
    registerForContextMenu(button1);
    registerForContextMenu(button2);
    registerForContextMenu(button3);
    registerForContextMenu(button4);
    registerForContextMenu(button5);
    registerForContextMenu(button6);
    registerForContextMenu(button7);
    registerForContextMenu(button8);
    registerForContextMenu(button9);
    registerForContextMenu(button10);
    registerForContextMenu(button11);
    registerForContextMenu(button12);
    registerForContextMenu(button13);
    registerForContextMenu(button14);
    registerForContextMenu(button15);
    registerForContextMenu(button16);
    registerForContextMenu(button17);
    registerForContextMenu(button18);
    registerForContextMenu(button19);
    registerForContextMenu(button20);
    registerForContextMenu(button21);
    registerForContextMenu(button22);
    registerForContextMenu(button23);
    registerForContextMenu(button24);
    registerForContextMenu(button25);

}

    // Using the Tag to allow for simple media playing coding.

    @Override
    public void onClick(View vv) {
        if (mp !=null) {mp.stop();}
        mp=MediaPlayer.create(this, ((Integer)vv.getTag()).intValue());
        mp.start();
    }

    // Create ContextMenu's.

    @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View vv, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, vv, menuInfo);
        contextMenuResource = ((((Integer) (vv.getTag())).intValue()));
        menu.setHeaderTitle(((Button)vv).getText());

        // contextMenuResource used here just to see what value it contains
        // when called it shows /res/raw/*.mp3 depending on which button

        menu.add(0, SAVE_SOUND, 0, contextMenuResource);
    }

    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        switch(item.getItemId()) {
            case SAVE_SOUND:

        AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

        // contextMenuResource used here just to see what value it contains
        // when called it shows at least a seven digit integer (which makes sense to me)

        dialogBuilder.setMessage("You selected " + contextMenuResource);
        dialogBuilder.setCancelable(true);
        dialogBuilder.create().show();

        // Creates a directory on the SDCard 

            File sddir = new File("/sdcard/NetApex/Ringtones");
            if (!sddir.mkdirs()) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Create dir on sdcard failed");  
                return false;
                }   

        // The rest is commented out since I can't get the data I would like in order
        // to copy the file to the SDCard

        /*  InputStream fIn = getBaseContext().getResources().openRawResource(contextMenuResource);
            int size = 0;
            size = fIn.available();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
            fIn.read(buffer);
            fIn.close();

            File rtNew = new File("/sdcard/NetApex/Ringtones"
            + contextMenuResource
            +".mp3");

            FileOutputStream rtFOS = null;
            rtFOS = new FileOutputStream(rtNew);
            rtFOS.write(buffer);
            rtFOS.flush();
            rtFOS.close();  */

            return true;  
        }
        return false;      
    }

    // Options menu created just to see it created

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.layout.menu, menu);

        return true;
    }

    // This makes the selection work

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch(item.getItemId()) {

        case R.id.quit:
            finish();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`contextMenuResource` is the value of a raw resource ID. You should not be attempting to use it as a title for a context menu choice, as you are here:

```
menu.add(0, SAVE_SOUND, 0, contextMenuResource);
```

You do not appear to be using `contextMenuResource` anywhere else, and since you did not explain what your symptoms actually are, I'm having to guess.

Comment: I was using it there just to see what the value was that it was reporting, which in that case turned out to be /res/raw/*.mp3 depending on which button it was that was long pressed.  (Which is exactly the value I was hoping for)

When I called in as:

    dialogBuilder.setMessage("You selected " + contextMenuResource);

it gave a totally different response  (2167480 for example).  That is where my confusion is.

Comment: I will say this again: You should not be attempting to use it as a title for a context menu choice. It is not a string resource ID -- it is a raw resource ID, and the two are not interchangeable. You are getting strange results from doing something you are not supposed to be doing, precisely because it is going to give you strange results.

Comment: Got ya, making the changes now.  Fingers crossed and holding a four leaf clover.

Comment: You are a pure genius.  It worked exactly as it was supposed to (verses how I was thinking it should - which was my problem).  Now making the phone recognize that it can use the files for ringtones or notifications is my last hold up.  I mistakenly found a way to make the phone scan the card for media files so now it plays them in the normal playlist instead.  *Sigh*  There is always something!

Comment: "You are a pure genius." No on both counts, but thanks for the sentiment! I haven't actually fussed with setting or adding ringtones, so I have no particular advice in that area.

Answer (score 1):

in my opinion this is wrong on so many levels ... have you looked at this at all ? http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html Why you're trying to register all those buttons ? How your UI looks like ? You're already open the dilog - just inflate layout into that to display what you want  and do your actions.

Comment: The UI is pretty much a series of buttons.  A typical soundboard.  I will check out the suggested page though and see if there is a better way of doing it.  The issues though is still about being able to download the file based on which button is pressed.